# Is there a way in rPATH's conary recipe to get the verison of an existing package

Tags: rpath

i am trying ...

```
loadRecipe('existingpackage')
class NewPackage(PackageRecipe):
    name = 'newpackage-test'
    p = existingpackage.version
    print p
```

but getting error, that existingpackage is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it right that loadRecipe needs the name of the package. But to access information from the recipe, you should use the **class** defined there, not the package name or the recipe filename. (That's also quite natural. Sometimes recipes can define more than one classes.)

For example, in a firefox plugin, I want the version of firefox, so that the plugin can be installed to the right place.

```
loadRecipe('firefox')
class FirefoxPackageSearch(PackageRecipe):

    [snip]

    def setup(r):
        [snip]
        r.macros.ff_version = '.'.join(FireFox.version.split('.')[:2])
```

I load the firefox recipe and use **Firefox.version** to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

since conary is just like (almost) coding in python:

p = .version
    print 'your package's Version Number: ' + p
    rhs = p.split("_",1)
    print 'Latest Your Package's Changeset: ' + rhs[1]